# to_int: how to allow coerce of TrueClass into Fixnum

Tags: ruby

I tried extending the Boolean classes like so:

```
class TrueClass def to_i() 1 end end
class TrueClass def to_int() 1 end end

class FalseClass def to_i() 0 end end
class FalseClass def to_int() 0 end end
```

But `1 * true` still throws `true can't be coerced into Fixnum`

Comment: Great article explain the coercion pattern in Ruby [Class Coercion in Ruby](https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2011/01/25/class-coercion-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [the article in the comment](https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2011/01/25/class-coercion-in-ruby), **tl;dr** would be:

```
class TrueClass
  def to_i
    1
  end

  def coerce(other)
    [other, other.is_a?(Numeric) ? to_i : self]
  end
end

1 * true # => 1
```

If you want to do arithmetic with booleans only, you may remove the conditional, but this might have side effects.